# What is the moment of inertia of this object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I have the following task, and am not sure what I am doing it wrong. Help would be truly appreciated!

**Task:**

A ping-pong ball has a mass *m*, and a radius *r*. Assume that one ping-pong ball can be modeled as a hollow sphere, with I = 2/3mr<sup>2</sup>. Three ping-pong balls are glued together in a line, as in the image below.

[image]

What is the moment of inertia through the y-axis?

**How I tried to solve it:**

I figured I should use the parallel-axis theorem I<sub>r</sub> = I<sub>0</sub> + Mr<sup>2</sup>.

I<sub>0</sub> = 2/3mr<sup>2</sup> * 3 = 2mr<sup>2</sup>

Also, Mr<sup>2</sup> = 3m * (2r)<sup>2</sup> = 12mr<sup>2</sup>. Adding these together I get 2mr<sup>2</sup> + 12mr<sup>2</sup> = 14mr<sup>2</sup>

However, the right answer is 22mr<sup>2</sup>. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is calculating $I_0$, because the center of mass of the three balls system pass trough the center of only one of the three ball. You have to use the parallel-axis theorem also for calculating $I_0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now, and next time I post a question I will make it a conceptual question, instead of directly asking for homework help. This did help me very much with my understanding of the parallel axis theorem :)

Comment: That is not correct. Calculating $I_0$ does not involve the parallel axis theorem.